# Named sets of permutations

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, big-list, permutations

I am looking into interesting subsets of permutations,
and there are several classes of permutations which are named.
For example, there are

- Derangements,
- Alternating,
- Grassmann permutations (at most one descent),
- Bi-Grassmannian, wher both $\sigma$ an $\sigma^{-1}$ are Grassmann
- Vexillary permutations (avoids 2143),
- Richardson permutations,
- [Wachs permutations](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2212.04932.pdf), (*has anyone actually counted these?!*)
- The even permutations, $A_n$.
- Flattened permutations (obtained from some  set partition by removing the 'bars')

I am sure there are many more subsets of permutations with special names,
and I would like to get some references for these (I plan to list them at my web-site [www.symmetricfunctions.com](https://www.symmetricfunctions.com) ).

Comment: Dominant = 132-avoiding; fully commutative = 321-avoiding

Comment: @SamHopkins Any references for  this particular use of terminology?

Comment: These are standard terms in the Schubert calculus/Coxeter world. For example, check out the Billey-Jockusch-Stanley paper where they are explored. The article on permutations at FindStat (https://www.findstat.org/CollectionsDatabase/Permutations/) also has a short list of permutation classes significant to Schubert calculus.

Comment: You might also be interested in Bridget Tenner's website devoted to pattern avoidance: https://math.depaul.edu/~bridget/patterns.html. If you click "view the entire database" you can see many classes of permutations defined by avoidance: e.g., stack sortable, fully commutative, dominant, vexillary, etc.

Comment: @ "has anyone actually counted those": Propositions 3.2 and 3.4 in the preprint you cited give bijections.

Comment: @darijgrinberg ah, ok thanks! It was not in the OEIS (but I just made a ticket).

Answer (score 4):

Some classes from the index entry "permutation" of EC1: André, connected, indecomposable, reverse alternating, separable, SIF (stabilized-interval-free), simple, simsun, Sundaram, standard. Also down-up and zigzag are synonyms for alternating, and up-down for reverse alternating. EC2 has Baxter, reduced Baxter, deque-sortable, smooth, stack-sortable, and 2-stack sortable.